# fileUpload using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am doing file uploading using angularjs. I am getting response but can't store that file into local disk.

### controller

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.message')
    .controller('MessageController', MessageController);

/** @ngInject */
MessageController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'fileUpload'];
function MessageController($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, fileUpload)
{
    var vm = this;



    vm.uploadFile = function(){

        var file = $scope.myFile;

        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);

        var uploadUrl = "./uploads";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };
}
})();
```

### service

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('fileUpload', fileUpload);

/** @ngInject */
function fileUpload()
{
    console.log('dsfsdfdsf');

      this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
          console.log('inside');
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

           $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
           })

           .success(function(){
           })

           .error(function(){
           });
    }
    return this;
}
}());
```

### view

```
<div flex style="max-width:700px;">
    <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
    <button ng-click = "vm.uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>
```

In console i am getting file details but i is not store in the disk.
The error is always shows like fileUpload is undefined in controller.

[image: Console error pic]

Comment: i think you should remove injection of your service named 'fileUpload' from
MessageController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'fileUpload'];
Only keep it within 
function MessageController($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, fileUpload)

Comment: thank you. I removed 'fileUpload' from MessageController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'fileUpload']; Now it's working properly.

Comment: now i'm posting my comment as answer if it help you please accept it or vote up for me...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.message')
    .controller('MessageController', MessageController);

/** @ngInject */
MessageController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$rootScope'];
function MessageController($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, fileUpload)
{
    var vm = this;



    vm.uploadFile = function(){

        var file = $scope.myFile;

        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);

        var uploadUrl = "./uploads";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };
}
})();
```

Comment: after request to sent to node file it shows error like Unexpected Field. What should i do now? Help me

Comment: i am getting error like                                                                              { [Error: Unexpected field]
  code: 'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE',
  field: 'file',
  storageErrors: [] } . I solved that problem, thanks for your concern.

Comment: i think you are uploading multiple files but receiving in single field in your app.js file...refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798593/getting-error-unexpected-field-when-trying-to-upload-multiple-files

Answer (score 0):

you forget $**rootScope** injection

```
/** @ngInject */
MessageController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$location','$rootScope', 'fileUpload'];
function MessageController($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, fileUpload)
{
    var vm = this;



    vm.uploadFile = function(){

        var file = $scope.myFile;

        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);

        var uploadUrl = "./uploads";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };
}
})();
```